# ionic toggle with ng-true-value doesn't change the model inside the controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I use Ionic toggle with on-change function, it works fine.

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="pushNotification.checked"
     ng-change="pushNotificationChange()">
```

After adding ng-true-value and ng-false-value the model is not changed, or at least not in on-change function. It changes within the view however, showing binded value correctly.

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="emailNotification"
     ng-true-value="'Subscribed'"
     ng-false-value="'Unubscribed'"
     ng-change="emailNotificationChange()">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
  console.log('Push Notification Change', $scope.pushNotification.checked);
};

$scope.emailNotificationChange = function() {
  console.log('Email Notification Change', $scope.emailNotification);
};
```

Here's the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqjjZP

Push Notifications toggle **logs** correctly to the console, while Newsletter toggle always **logs** 'Subscribed'.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `ng-model` performance 2-way binding only when bound to an object which can be **updated via reference**. In your case your `$scope.pushNotification` is an object and that's why it works correct while `$scope.emailNotification` is a primitive value and doesn't work. Change it to an object and it will work even without the change handler.

```
<ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-assertive"
    ng-model="emailNotification.value"
    ng-true-value="'Subscribed'"
    ng-false-value="'Unubscribed'">
  Newsletter
</ion-toggle>


 $scope.emailNotification = { value: 'Subscribed' };
```

I have created a forked codepen from your code and it works as expected: https://codepen.io/addi90/pen/EKqaOG

Answer (score 0):

Well I looked at your code and your ng-model binds directly to `ng-true-value`and `ng-false-value`. So when removing `$scope.emailNotification = 'Subscribed';` from the controller the button still works but the logging wil say undefined.

The button will have no value at the start, but will get it when you toggle it.